# Why on network node not create tap* interface when created instance?

Tags: openstack, openvswitch, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

OS RHEL 7.2, openstack release - kilo. I have 4 node: controller, network, compute and block storage.

I have some problem. When I create instance on Horizon, he get IP, but in network node not create tap*-interfaces. I look neutron and nova logs, there are no mistakes. Config files for nova and neutron is default. I set up their of official manual of kilo (install-guide).

ip a on network node:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:09:c4:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.3.105/24 brd 172.28.3.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe09:c460/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:09:c4:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.30.1/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global ens224
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe09:c46a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ens256: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:09:c4:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe09:c474/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether ee:df:b1:25:79:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-tun: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 1a:ab:4c:9e:ca:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br-int: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether ea:90:62:a0:5f:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 00:0c:29:09:c4:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ovs-vsctl show:

```
3c70ed9e-44f1-4fc7-99b5-69175fd0738e
    Bridge br-ex
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
        Port phy-br-ex
            Interface phy-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ex}
        Port "ens256"
            Interface "ens256"
    Bridge br-tun
        fail_mode: secure
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
        Port "gre-0a0a1e02"
            Interface "gre-0a0a1e02"
                type: gre
                options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.10.30.1", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.10.30.2"}
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
        Port "gre-0a0a1e03"
            Interface "gre-0a0a1e03"
                type: gre
                options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.10.30.1", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.10.30.3"}
        Port "gre-0a0a1e04"
            Interface "gre-0a0a1e04"
                type: gre
                options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.10.30.1", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.10.30.4"}
    Bridge br-int
        fail_mode: secure
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
        Port "tape0c64f84-38"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tape0c64f84-38"
                type: internal
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.5.0"
```

neutron net-show int-net:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | True                                 |
| id                        | a7cad61c-f1d5-4093-9278-d607ecb55d25 |
| mtu                       | 0                                    |
| name                      | int-net                              |
| provider:network_type     | gre                                  |
| provider:physical_network |                                      |
| provider:segmentation_id  | 29                                   |
| router:external           | False                                |
| shared                    | False                                |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   | 93899c4c-f343-45fc-8bc4-5d9fd0740d6c |
| tenant_id                 | a8c7d88dc47b4af6a3214ebef41db2d7     |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

nova list:

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| ID                                   | Name  | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks            |
+--------------------------------------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 26965f32-0fd7-4494-ae93-02a82d550b31 | test3 | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | int-net=192.168.3.9 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

neutron.conf on network node:

```
[DEFAULT]
verbose = True
core_plugin = ml2
service_plugins = router
auth_strategy = keystone
allow_overlapping_ips = True
rpc_backend=rabbit

[keystone_authtoken]
auth_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_url = http://controller:35357
auth_plugin = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = DataPasbaSEWort692

[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = $state_path/lock

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_hosts = 172.28.3.102:$rabbit_port,172.28.3.107:$rabbit_port
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = openstack
```

ml2.conf on network node:

```
[ml2]
type_drivers = flat,vlan,gre,vxlan
tenant_network_types = gre
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch

[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = external

[ml2_type_gre]
tunnel_id_ranges = 1:1000

[securitygroup]
enable_security_group = True
enable_ipset = True
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver

[ovs]
local_ip = 10.10.30.1
bridge_mappings = external:br-ex

[agent]
tunnel_types = gre
```

l3-agent:

```
[DEFAULT]
verbose = True
interface_driver = neutron.agent.linux.interface.OVSInterfaceDriver
external_network_bridge =
router_delete_namespaces = True
```

Comment: You would expect to see `tap*` interface on the *compute* node, where the actual vm is running, not on the *network* node.

Comment: Thanks. I see interfaces in compute node, but my VM not ping and gateway address not ping.

Comment: Have you created an appropriate security to allow the inbound network traffic?

Comment: Problem was in this. I add rules and he now working.